# Python: Split timestamp by date and hour

Tags: python, split, timestamp

I have a list of timestamps in the following format:

> 1/1/2013 3:30

I began to learn python some weeks ago and I have no idea how to split the date and time. Can anyone of you help me?

Output should be on column including

> 1/1/2013

and one column including

> 3:30

Comment: Does the list contain actual datetime objects, or just strings?

Comment: I think I have to revise my question a bit, sry. I have a csv file which includes 19 columns.

In column 10 the timestamps looks as above mentioned.

I want to split the column with the timestamps and add 2 new columns including the output of the script.

Comment: If I have answered your question please mark the answer as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is `str.split` ...

```
>>> s = '1/1/2013 3:30'
>>> s.split()
['1/1/2013', '3:30']
```

If it's in a list, you can do with a list-comprehension:

```
>>> lst = ['1/1/2013 3:30', '1/2/2013 3:30']
>>> [s.split() for s in lst]
[['1/1/2013', '3:30'], ['1/2/2013', '3:30']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this date and time further in your code to perform operations on this data such as comparing dates, you can convert this timestamp to datetime objects. Refer the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) on datetime module.

You can use the following code to convert your timestamp to datetime object.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime("1/1/2013 3:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
>>> timestamp
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 3, 30)
>>> timestamp.date()
datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)
>>> timestamp.time()
datetime.time(3, 30)
```

If you just want to strip date and time to use them as strings, use method suggested by [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson).

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudocode to accomplish what you had mentioned in your comment:

```
f = file("path/to/file.csv", "r")
timestamp_column = 10

def get_updated_row(i, row):
    row = row.split(',')

    try:
        timestamp = row.pop(timestamp_column) #remove column

        if i == 0:
            #header
            row.extend(["date", "time"]) #add columns

        else:
            #normal row
            date = timestamp[0]
            time = timestamp[1]
            row.extend([date, time])

    except IndexError:
        print("ERROR: Unable to parse row {0}".format(i))

    return ','.join(row)

with f.read() as csv:
    for i, row in enumerate(csv):
        print(get_updated_row(i, row)) #write to file here instead if necessary
```